# How does oracle manage a hash partition

Tags: oracle, hash, partitioning

I understand the concept of range partitioning. If i have a date column and i partition on that column based on month, then if my query has a where clause just filtering for a month, then i can hit a particular partition and get my data, without hitting the full table.

In Oracle docs i read that if a logical partitioning like 'month' is not available,(e.g, you partition on a column called customer id) ,then use a hash partitioning. So how will this work? Oracle will randomly divide the data and assign it to different partitions and assign a hash code to each partition?

But in this situation, when new data comes in, how does oracle know in which partition to put the new data? And when i query data, it seems there is no way to avoid hitting multiple partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "how does oracle know in which partition to put the new data?"

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/parpart.htm#CIHBHGCE)

> Oracle Database uses a linear hashing algorithm and to prevent data
>   from clustering within specific partitions, you should define the
>   number of partitions by a power of two (for example, 2, 4, 8).

As for your other question ...

> "when i query data, it seems there is no way to avoid hitting multiple
>   partitions?"

If you're searching for a single Customer ID then no.  Oracle's hashing algorithm is consistent, so records with the same partition key end up in the same partition (obviously).  But if you are searching for, say, *all the new customers from the last month* then yes.  Oracle's hashing algorithm will strive to distribute records evenly so the latest records will be spread across the whole table.

So the real question is, why do we choose to partition a table?  Performance is often the *least compelling reason* to partition.  Better reasons include

- **availability** each partition can reside on a different tablespace.  Hence a problem with a tablespace will take out a slice of the table's data instead of the whole thing.
- **management** partitioning provides a mechanism for splitting whole table jobs into clear batches.  Partition exchange can make it easier to bulk load data.

As for performance, physical co-location of records can speed up some queries- those which are searching records by a defined range of keys.  However, any queries which don't match the grain of the query won't perform faster (and may even perform slower) than a non-partitioned table.

Hash partitioning is unlikely to provide performance benefits, precisely because it shuffles the keys across the whole table.  It will provide the availability and manageability benefits of partitioning (but is obviously not particularly amenable to partition exchange).

Comment: Thanks."availability each partition can reside on a different tablespace" - so each tablespace can reside on a different machine? Is this something like sharding?

Answer (score 3):

A hash is not random, it divides the data in a repeatable (but perhaps difficult-to-predict) fashion so that the same ID will always map to the same partition.

Oracle uses a hash algorithm that *should* usually spread the data evenly between partitions.